# c# Why is this line requiring a cast?

Tags: c#, casting

```
// A single blog entry
public class BlogEntry
{
    public string ID;
    public string Title;
    public string Entry;
    public DateTime Date;
    public int UserID;

    // Load an entry based on ID
    public BlogEntry(int EntryID)
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var q = (from Blog in db.tblBlogEntries where Blog.ID == EntryID select Blog).Single();

        // Fill data
        this.ID = EntryID;
        this.Title = q.title;
        this.Entry = q.entry;
        this.Date = (DateTime)q.date;
        this.UserID = (int)q.userID;
    }
}
```

`this.ID = EntryID` is throwing the error:

> Cannot implicity turn type 'string' to
>   'int'

I'm baffled, because they are both defined as integers, quite explicitly!

Comment: Are you sure it's not "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'" on `where Blog.ID == EntryID`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your class definition, ID is defined as String

```
 public string ID;
```

and you are trying to assing an `int`.
That's why.

Answer (score 4):

Momentary blindness?

```
public string ID;
```

Comment: But shouldn't the error message be different? After all he's trying to convert an `int` to a `string` implicitly and not the other way round.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: the error message *is* different; the OP was probably quoting from memory and made a mistake.

Answer (score 4):

You've got 'ID' defined at class level as a string.

Answer (score 2):

Your class says `string ID`.
You can't put an `int` into that.

Answer (score 2):

`this.ID` is defined as string, and EntryID is the `integer` parameter. That code won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Ummm.. no they are not `ID` is string and  `UserId` is an int

```
public string ID;
public int UserID;
```

Answer (score 1):

A very good example showing why you should not use similar and ambiguous field names.

```
public string ID;
public int UserID;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this:

```
// Fill data         
this.UserID = EntryID;
```

It's an awkward semantic situation as far as the names of your fields go, so check your logic over carefully and make sure you're assigning the right value to the right property.